# Fetch records in STI for empty has_many records in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, hide, record

I have a model Gallery that  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy and Image model that belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true. Single Table Inheritance is being used here. Now I want to fetch and hide the Galleries which don't have images associated to it. How to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to most effectively fetch all galleries with an empty association, you could use this scope:

```
# in Gallery.rb

scope :no_images, -> {
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN images ON images.imageable_id = galleries.id).
  group('galleries.id').
  having('count(imageable_id) = 0') }
```

Running `Gallery.no_images` would return all `Gallery`objects with no associated images.

Please note that the docs have the following to say about using polymorphic associations with Single Table Inheritance:

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table
>   inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to
>   work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI
>   models in the type column of the polymorphic association. To continue
>   with the asset example above, suppose there are guest posts and member
>   posts that use the posts table for STI. In this case, there must be a
>   type column in the posts table.

So ensure that you have properly set the `type` column to the correct value (`"Image" in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Gallery.all.each do |gallery|
   galleries << gallery if (gallery.images.empty?)
end
```